# SQL Server : creating stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure which should take `CustomerID` as a parameter and return `Name` from `atbv_Contacts`, where the parameter of `ContactID` column is the same as `CustomerID`.

My problem is that I guess I'm only trying to get ID, therefore it won't show me the Customer's ID. Plus I don't think that this procedure is written correctly as I get the following errors:

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Procedure atsp_GetNameID, Line 7
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
>
> Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Procedure strg_Database_ChangeLog, Line 90
>   Invalid object name. Please check for a typo.

My current code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE atsp_GetNameID 
    (@CustomerID AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ContactID
    FROM atbv_Contacts
    WHERE ContactID LIKE '%' + @CustomerID + '%'
END
```

Comment: This looks as though you have a DDL trigger in the database called `strg_Database_ChangeLog` that is calling `RAISERROR` and rolling back your `CREATE` attempt.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Interesting.  I didn't realize that the trigger would be called even before the stored procedure is parsed.

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix this? :?

Comment: @TesteroniPeperoni . . . Remove the DDL trigger.  Or, create the stored procedure in a database that you have more control over and where you have permission to create stored procedures.  Note:  you will then get another error (which is addressed in my deleted answer).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The `'%' + @CustomerID + '%'` will parse fine and allow the procedure to be created. The `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.` will happen when the proc is executed at run time.

Answer (score -1):

Replace with this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE atsp_GetNameID 
    (@CustomerID AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ContactID
    FROM atbv_Contacts
    WHERE ContactID =@CustomerID
END
```

Comment: That neither fixes the problem nor addresses the actual error.